# Which SE for Motorcycle Questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a motorcycle question, but I'm suprised to find that there is no motorcycle stack exchange, not even in Area 51!

According to [this answer](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/683/34148), motorcycles are off-topic on the bicycles stack exchange.

**Where should I ask motorcycle questions?**

Some options:

1. Mechanics SE
2. Start a Motorcycle SE in Area 51

Comment: Good work for asking, but they're definitely off-topic for bicycles.  There is some grey area/overlap with electric-assist bikes and to some extent liquid-fuel bikes provided they have pedal components, but in reality most of the liquid fuel bikes are ridden fully on motor, not using the motor as an assist to pedalling.

Answer (score 3):

### [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)

According to [this post](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1607/28301), motorcycle questions are **on-topic** on the mechanics stack exchange.

A motorcycle SE was proposed in Area 51, but it failed to gain traction.